# line integral for lapacian of green function

Tags: integration, line-integrals

I was proving that
$$-\Delta_x G(x-y)=\delta_y \text { on } D^{\prime}\left(\mathbb{R}^3\right) $$

but during the calculation there is
$$\frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon^2} \int_{\partial B_{\varepsilon}(y)} d \sigma(x) \varphi(x) \underset{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} \varphi(y)
$$
my question is why?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the explicit formula for $d\sigma(x)$ for a sphere of radius $\epsilon$?